# Attempting to transition from a JavaScript Alert to a Bootstrap Modal when a list row is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some working code that imports some JSON data via AJAX and builds an HTML table.  When a line in the table is clicked, a JavaScript alert pops up with the information from that line.  Since it does not look too good, I wanted to try using a Bootstrap Modal instead.

I have researched and reviewed how to do this, but something is not working.  There are some topics on this in Stack Overflow, but none seem to address what I seem to be missing.

When I comment out the line of code for the alert and add the `$(#focusModal).modal('show');` code for the Modal, the code breaks.  The table is not even generated and I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token error" in Chrome.

FYI: The JSON data is from a file being served locally using Node.js.  Sample JSON data is included below.

HTML sample:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Create Table From JSON</title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <h1>Academy Awards For Best Actress</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="jsonTable"></div>

        <!-- Button for testing Modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#focusModal">Open Modal</button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="focusModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>      
    </body>


</html>
```

JavaScript Sample:

```
function TableFromJSON(){
    //AJAX(via jQuery) to request JSON data
    var jsonData;
    $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/academy_award_actresses.json", function(data){
        jsonData = data;
        BuildTable(jsonData);
    });
}   


function BuildTable(jsonData){  
    //Get the header values
    var headerArr = [];
    for(var key in jsonData[0]){
        headerArr.push(key);
    }

    //Create table and header row
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.className = "table table-bordered table-striped table-hover"
    var tableRow = table.insertRow(-1);

    for(var i = 0; i < headerArr.length; i++){
        var tableHeader = document.createElement("th");
        tableHeader.innerHTML = headerArr[i];
        tableRow.appendChild(tableHeader);
    }

    //Add data and rows
    for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        tableRow = table.insertRow(-1);
        for(var j = 0; j < headerArr.length; j++) {
            var cell = tableRow.insertCell(-1);
            cell.innerHTML = jsonData[i][headerArr[j]];
        }


    }

    //Add table to div container
    var tableContainer = document.getElementById("jsonTable");
    tableContainer.appendChild(table);

}


$(document).ready(function(){
    TableFromJSON();
    //jQuery for click alert functionality
    $(document).on("click", "tr", function(){
        $(#focusModal).modal('show');
        //alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

JSON Sample:

```
[
    {
        "year": "1970",
        "actress": "Glenda Jacson",
        "movie": "Women in Love"
    },
    {
        "year": "1971",
        "actress": "Jane Fonda",
        "movie": "Klute"
    },
    {
        "year": "1972",
        "actress": "Liza Minnelli",
        "movie": "Cabaret"
    },
    {
        "year": "1973",
        "actress": "Glenda Jacson",
        "movie": "A Touch of Class"
    }
]
```

Comment: missing quotes for jQuery selector for modal ... `$(#focusModal) ==> $('#focusModal')`. Look at error thrown in browser console

Comment: Haha, wow....  I don't want to admit how much time I spent trying to solve this...  Terrible...  Thanks a bunch!  Sorry Stack Overflow for such a stupid question.